# Rails rendering JSON data with Model Root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I've got some data in Rails that I want to render as JSON data. What I'm doing right now is simply finding all instances of a Model and calling render :json=>data.

```
data = Data.find(:all)
render :json => data
```

However, Rails is including the model name in each JSON object. So my JSON data ends up looking like this:

```
[{modelname:{propertyName: 'value',...}},{modelname:{propertyName: 'value2',...}}]
```

instead of this:
    [{propertyName:'value',...},{propertyName:'value2',...}]

The modelname is always the same and I don't want it to be there.

I changed the option to render the root in the JSON data in one of the Rails initializers but that affects everything that I want rendered as JSON, which I don't want to do for this project.

In this case, I want to be able to do this on a case-by-case basis.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

With Rails 3, you can use active_model_serializers gem[1](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

that allows you to specify rootless rendering of an object like this:

```
render :json => data, :root => false
```

Comment: This worked great for me, although that period should probably be a comma?

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a way to do this by passing options to the to_json method (and I don't believe there is such an option). You have more alternative to do this, any class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base will have include_root_in_json.

Do something like this.

```
Data.include_root_in_json = false
data = Data.find(:all)
render :json => data
```

Hope this gets you going.

Ok let's try this then.

```
DataController < ApplicationControlle

  private

  def custom_json(data)
    Data.include_root_in_json = false
    data.to_json
    Data.include_root_in_json = true
    data
  end
end
```

Then your redirect would look like this

```
data = Data.find(:all)
render :json => custom_json(data)
```

It's pretty silly code I wish I could think of something else entirely. Let me ask you this: What is it about having the model name included in the json data ?

Comment: I just tried this, and it has the effect of changing include_root_in_json to false globally, unfortunately. I'm running Rails 2.3.5, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 3, I found this way better to do. Override the `as_json` in your model and do as follows:

```
def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge :methods => [:some_method_that_you_want_to_include_result], :include => {:child_relation => {:include => :grand_child_relation } })
end
```